# how do I print multiple strings that were entered into a while loop, and then split using .split into a list? using python

Tags: python

I am having trouble printing all of the data points entered in a while loop. Some context, user enters patient number, and 3 different body temps on each new line of the while loop. Each of the entered data is split using .split Problem is I can only get one of these entered lines to print.

I've slimmed it down to make it easier to read but here is what I have tried.

```
PT_list = {}
while patient != '':
   ....
   ....
   ....
   PT_list[i] = total[0], average, diagnosis

for num in PT_list:
   print(total[0], round(average, 2), diagnosis)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, you're printing only the last patient (from what I can understand). You're not actually accessing the data you've stored in your `PT_list` (by using the `while`-loop.

What you want to do is to iterate over each element in your dictionary (`PT_list`) and access its data in your iteration, but only from the current element, if you understand, what I mean.

So, you need to replace just the last line in your code:

```py
# Mind the indentation
  print(PT_list[num][0], round(PT_list[num][1], 2), PT_list[num][2])
```

Since you're storing data in your dictionary as a number mapped to a tuple (consisting of `3` elements), you can just access the requested data using indicies. Keep in mind, you need to respect the order of how you store the data in the tuple / dict.

Therefore:

```
PT_list[num][0] -> total
PT_list[num][1] -> average
PT_list[num][2] -> diagnosis
```

Answer (score 0):

This method should also work:

```
for tot, avg, diag in PT_list:
   print(tot, round(avg, 2), diag)
```